# Adding an image attachment to a wiki page programmatically using RestAPI through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, connection, wiki, ibm-sbt

I tried attaching an image as attachment to existing wiki page using RestAPI.

Followed this link http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Adding_an_attachment_to_a_wiki_page&content=apicontent

I am able to create the attachment to the wiki but it is getting corrupted when opened.Am i doing any thing wrong i sent SLug header as `test.png` and nonce as `1aae1966-9baf-416b-bb4c-24fe6ca7c298` and content as some binary data

Any sample examples to attach an image as attachment in WIKI page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using the SBT? or raw connections API? it seems raw api.  can you share the log of the request?

Comment: Request Headers : Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length 
1312752
Content-Type 
image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8
Cookie 
JSESSIONID=0000OWZ06ft8gp9guJ9MpmGs4fY:-1
Host 
localhost:9443
Referer 
https://localhost:9443/SampleSBT/PublishedWiki.html
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
X-Requested-With 
XMLHttpRequest
X-Update-Nonce 
01c5e775-d5a0-462e-9fa5-3d4649090b26
slug 
sri.jpeg

Comment: var file = document.getElementById("wFile").files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(e) {
//passed reader.result in request
}
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

Answer (score 0):

here is a curl command showing how to add attachment

```
curl -u "<EMAIL>:<PASSWORD>" -X POST -H "X-Update-Nonce: <NONCE>" -H "Content-Type: <CONTENT_TYPE>" -H "Slug: <FILENAME>" --data "@<FILE>" "https://<SERVER>/wikis/basic/api/wiki/<WIKI>/page/<WIKIPAGE>/feed?category=attachment"
```

Comment: Can you please show me the same thing in javascript.Please

Comment: in your sample, the data that you are adding to your Post request does not contain the file's binary content. It's just passing the name of the file. And that's the reason your file is uploaded for 242B. 
No issues in rest code. Please check how to upload binary data to the post request.